# Second foreach in the loop returns bool(false) though array is present

Tags: php

In my code below the data is extracted correctly for the first `foreach`, but doesn't return anything for 2nd `foreach` although selected one present inside the 2nd `foreach`. I still get the error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() for line `foreach ($authorlist as $post)`...

However the 2nd `foreach` returns data correctly as soon as I remove the first `foreach` loop.

Below is my code

```
<?php

$all= get_posts(array('post_type' => 'books', 'numberposts' => -1,));

foreach ( $all as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);

    if (!empty($post))
    {
     $booklink = array();

     $booklist = get_field('booklist'); 
               foreach ($booklist as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
                    if (!empty($post))
                        {
                        $booklink[] = strip_tags(get_field('booklink',$post));                                       
                        }
                endforeach;
                wp_reset_postdata();
     echo $booklink[0];  

     $authorname = array();

     $authorlist = get_field('authorlist'); 
               foreach ($authorlist as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
                    if (!empty($post))
                        {
                        $authorname[] = strip_tags(get_field('authorname',$post));                                       
                        }
                endforeach;
                wp_reset_postdata();
echo $authorname[0]; 

    }
endforeach;
?>
```

I did `var_dump($authorlist)` and it returns `bool(false)` as long as `foreach ($booklist as $post)`  loop is present. The moment I remove that loop then the dump shows the data of the `authorlist` correctly. How to get both the loops working together?

You can see the output [here](http://myproject.byethost7.com/wp/?page_id=6)

added unset and change$post for each foreach still not working

```
<?php

$all= get_posts(array('post_type' => 'books', 'numberposts' => -1,));
echo "VAR_DUMP(all) <br>";
var_dump($all);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
foreach ( $all as $post ): setup_postdata($post);

    if (!empty($post))
    {
     $booklink = array();

     $booklist = get_field('booklist'); 
               foreach ($booklist as $bookpost): setup_postdata($bookpost);
                    if (!empty($bookpost))
                        {
                        $booklink[] = strip_tags(get_field('booklink',$bookpost));                                       
                        }

        endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        unset($bookpost);


    echo "<br>";
    echo "var dump for booklist";
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump( $booklist);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
     echo "booklink is - " . $booklink[0]."<br>";  

     $authorname = array();

     $authorlist = get_field('authorlist'); 
               foreach ($authorlist as $authorpost): setup_postdata($authorpost);

                    if (!empty($authorpost))
                        {
                        $authorname[] = strip_tags(get_field('authorname',$authorpost));                                       
                        }

                endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();        
                unset($authorpost);

    echo "<br>";
    echo "var dump for authorlist";
   echo "<br>";
    var_dump( $authorlist);
    echo "<br>";
   echo "<br>"; 
     echo "authorname is - ".$authorname[0]."<br>"; 

    }

endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
unset($post);
?>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but I don't see any reason for any of your calls to `setup_postdata()` and `wp_reset_postdata()`. What happens when you remove them both?

Comment: nothing ...result is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out by mrwweb and I quote from him

> ...but I don't see any reason for any of your calls to `setup_postdata()` and `wp_reset_postdata()`

You are not trying to setup new posts here, just retrieving existing data from within the post which is already setup

The main reason for your problem is the use of the variable `$post` in all of your `foreach` loops. This creates a clash in the `foreach` loop following the previous one as the `$post` reference still remains after the `foreach` loop, thus the unexpected output. Here is what the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) have to say

> **Warning**
>
> Reference of a `$value` and the last array element remain even after the `foreach` loop. It is recommended to destroy it by `unset()`.

So, as possible solutions, you can either rename the `$post` variable to be unique in every `foreach` loop, or as recommended, `unset($post)` after each `foreach`.

Just on a side note, do not use `:` and `endforeach`, rather use curly brackets (`{}`). Curly brackets makes your code easier to debug and to read, and curly brackets are supported by all code editors, where as your method is not

**EDIT**

As explained, you should remove `wp_reset_postdata()` and `setup_postdata()` from you two `foreach` loops that is inside the main `foreach` loop. I have also totally rearranged your code. You have to check if your `array_expression` is not empty **before** the `foreach` and wrap that whole `foreach` loop in that conditional statement.

There is also absolutely no use in checking if `$value` is empty inside the `foreach` loop, it **will** always have a value for as long as there is something inside your `array_expression`. If your `array_expression` is empty, you will get the following error regardless if you check if `Svalue` is not empty

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

This is how your code should look like (*PLEASE NOTE: this is untested*)

```
<?php

$all= get_posts(array('post_type' => 'books', 'numberposts' => -1,));
echo "VAR_DUMP(all) <br>";
var_dump($all);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";


if( !empty( $all ) ) {

foreach ( $all as $post ){

    setup_postdata($post);

     $booklink = array();

     $booklist = get_field('booklist'); 

          if( !empty($booklist) ) {
               foreach ($booklist as $bookpost) { 
                    

                  $booklink[] = strip_tags(get_field('booklink',$bookpost)); 
                                  
 
               }

             unset($bookpost);
          }


    echo "<br>";
    echo "var dump for booklist";
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump( $booklist);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
     echo "booklink is - " . $booklink[0]."<br>";  

     $authorname = array();

     $authorlist = get_field('authorlist'); 

           if (!empty($authorlist)) {

               foreach ($authorlist as $authorpost) {


                        $authorname[] = strip_tags(get_field('authorname',$authorpost));                                       

                }
               
                unset($authorpost);

            }


    echo "<br>";
    echo "var dump for authorlist";
   echo "<br>";
    var_dump( $authorlist);
    echo "<br>";
   echo "<br>"; 
     echo "authorname is - ".$authorname[0]."<br>"; 


}
wp_reset_postdata();
unset($post);
}
?>
```

Comment: i added the unset plus also tried changing the $post to different variable still same output

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: ok awesome it works...thanx so so much

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)

Comment: can u help with this too http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159064/auto-order-posts-of-custom-post-type-by-title?noredirect=1#comment230458_159064